# jhipster-registry and keycloak : cors error getting service informations

Tags: jhipster, keycloak

I have a problem with jhispter-registry using keycloak (or okta) for authentication. My microservices stack is mde of registry in version 4.0.1 (but I hab same problem with version 3.3.0), a gateway and a microservice generated by jhipster version 5.3.0. I use keycloak version 4.3.0 in docker.

I manage to authenticate me on registry and gateway without problems.

When I call web service required authentication through gateway (by example http://127.0.0.1:8080/ws/auth), it's ok.

But on registry with administration menu, when I want look gateway configuration (or metrics, logs, ...), I got a cors error after 2 redirections :

1. from registry to gateway_ip/login: ok
2. from gateway to keyclok: cors error

And if I want configuration of my service, I got directly an error 401.

All services (registry (version 4.0.1), gateway (generated by jhipster 5.3.0), microservices (generated by version 5.3.0)  and keycloak (version 4.3.0 in docker) run in my PC. In /etc/hosts, I added ip 127.0.0.1 to keycloak. I use default configuration for all services, in dev profile.

Is it a bug of jhipster, or have I misconfigured my services ?

Thanks, Denis

Comment: Did you start your registry with the `oauth2` profile?  That's needed for managing OIDC apps through the registry (docs need updating to add the new profile)

Comment: Yes, it's started with dev, swagger and oauth2 profiles

Comment: I think it's a bug, I could reproduce your issue